# OOP Javascript using constructor as an object for static methods

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module

*I am always looking for new patterns to make code perform better and increase its readability.*

I am using a method such as this to set the prototypes of a class before init:

```
// Definition 

function SomeClass(){}

SomeClass.set = function(methName, fn){
    SomeClass.prototype[methName] = fn;
};

// Add a new method prior to initialization
SomeClass.set('doSomethingUnique', function(a, b){ return a / b * a - b });

// Instantiation
var test = new SomeClass();
test.doSomethingUnique(4, 5);
```

This way I am able to use a "self contained" setter in order to avoid typing the typical SomeClass.prototype.doSomethingUnique = function(){...}. I am also allowed to use static methods without instantiating the class, which I feel added much more freedom to javascript classes (and allows just the type of behavior demonstrated above.

I don't see any real negatives to doing this, and as I consider this a code improvement due to it making my end result more modular and readable - it makes me wonder why I don't see this often in common O/S code. Can anyone else see any reason not to use this style/technique for purposes such as the the one explained above?

Thanks SO!

Comment: Most people would probably consider it more readable, and just as easy, to just do `SomeClass.prototype.doSomethingUnique = function(a, b) {...`, but if wrapping that in a function makes you happy, go for it.

Comment: If you want to improve readability, use ES6 classes. Transpile if necessary.

Comment: Yes I understand for this very small optimization it is not necessarily worth it, however I mean the example above is meant to be more of a type of problem that could be solved with this approach.

Comment: I get that this is not typical, its not about that - its more about if there is anything wrong with the way I am doing it. I could use a getter and setter that could help dynamically generate methods and add delete edit properties and rename prototype methods or whatever one could possibly do prior to initializing the class.

Comment: modifying prototypes after instances are created can degrade performance, if that matters to your app.

Comment: @Bergi that does not help with this question. 

class X {
 
}

X.test = function(){
 alert('123');
}
X.test();  

Therefore the same thing could be asked about ES6 classes as it is the same exact thing under the hood. If its a es5 class or es6 class they will be able to have methods and properties added to them prior to being initialized.

Comment: @dandavis PRIOR to initializing the class, I have never modified a classes prototype after it is instantiated, didnt even know it was possible

Comment: @AlphaG33k: It's `class X { static test(){ alert('123'); } }` in ES6. That *does* help with readability.

Comment: @AlphaG33k: ahh, i thought that was the gimmick here. in that case, just tack them onto .prototype manually...

Comment: @AlphaG33k It's going to be slightly slower than just assigning them directly to the prototype. After all, you have to perform a function call and the engine has almost no options for optimizing the construction of the prototype since it's all done with strings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems counterintuitive.  Case in point, JS isn't exactly a classical OO language like C# and Java.  Even SomeClass.set() isn't really a static method since if you extend SomeClass, set() gets referenced in its child.

You're essentially accomplishing the same thing as the traditional Constructor.prototype.myMethod syntax in a convoluted way.  While it may seem more "readable" I think the intent goes above and beyond what most JS developers are accustomed too.  I say stick with convention unless the problem you're solving requires something else.

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I am unable to see how set becomes inherited...  http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/JGezaz. Could you please show me how set becomes inherited? Thanks DJSPIN80

Comment: Again, inherited is kind of the wrong word to use.  :)

Remember that in JavaScript, functions are objects too.  So set() is delegated to the TestClass function.  When you call 'new' in JavaScript, it does some funky magic and sets the prototype to itself.  'New' in JavaScript isn't the same in language like C# or Java.  So 'new' in this case doesn't delegate set() to the instance of your constructor function.  This is why we put things into MyClass.prototype.
Good read:
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects

Comment: Yes I understand how javascript works, I just didnt understand how you were seeing that method inherited. I actually do not want the set method to become inherited although still be a part of the same class